# I want to deploy the DB, API, and FRONT containers in the above repository to AWS ECS so that they can be operated

Tags: reactjs, django, postgresql, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

https://github.com/hodanov/react-django-postgres-sample-app
I want to deploy the DB, API, and FRONT containers in the above repository to AWS ECS so that they can be operated.

Therefore, in order to operate the containers separately, the docker-compose.yaml file was divided into containers.

I pushed the container to ECR and operated it with ECS, but it stopped by all means.
Where should I review it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time on this. Where do I start :)

First and foremost the compose file has bind mounts that can't work when you deploy to ECS/Fargate (because the local files mounted do not exist on the remote end). So these are the 3 things that needs to be done:

- you need to remove the bind mounts for the `rest_api` and the `web_front` services.
- you need to append `ADD ./code/django_rest_api/ /code` in `DockerfilePython` and append `ADD ./code/django_web_front/ /code` in `DockerfileNode`. This will basically simulate the bind mount and will include the content of the folder right in the image(s).
- you need to add the `image` field to the three services. That will allow you to `docker compose build` and docker compose push` so that the images are available to be deployed in the cloud.

This is my resulting compose file (you need to change your images repos):

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    container_name: django_db
    image: mreferre/django_db:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfilePostgres
    volumes:
      - django_data_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  rest_api:
    container_name: django_rest_api
    image: mreferre/django_rest_api:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfilePython
    command: ./run-migrate-and-server.sh
#    volumes:
#      - ./code/django_rest_api:/code
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  web_front:
    container_name: django_web_front
    image: mreferre/django_web_front:latest  
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerfileNode
    command: ./npm-install-and-start.sh
#    volumes:
#      - ./code/django_web_front:/code
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - rest_api
volumes:
  django_data_volume:
```

This will deploy just fine with `docker compose up` in the ECS context and the API server will work. HOWEVER, the React front end will not work because the `App.js` code points to localhost:

```
const constants = {
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/profile/?format=json"
}
```

I don't know what the React equivalent is but in Angular you need to point to something along the lines of `window.location.href` to tell the app to point to the same endpoint your browser connected to.

If you fix this problem then it *should* just work(tm).